# Sophie Germain primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history

Why did Germain come up with her Germain primes? I am intrigued to know why Sophie came across these primes.
Do they have any applications?

Comment: From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime): "Sophie Germain primes are named after French mathematician Sophie Germain, who used them in her investigations of Fermat's Last Theorem." She most probably did a lot of work on primes of that particular form, such that it was named in her honour.

Answer (score 3):

She solved a part of Fermat's last theorem, but only if the exponent is one of these primes.

Answer (score 1):

When Sophie Germain found out about Fermat's last theorem, she found a sort-of proof, that if the value of *n* was a Germain prime, that *x, y* or *z* would have to be a multiple of *n*. For more details of the proof, I recommend *Fermat's Last Theorem*, by Simon Sigh.